# Text not going to next line, staying on the same line as previous text

Tags: html, css

The text after the icons are not going under the icon no matter what I try; it is only staying on the right side of the icon:
https://jsfiddle.net/mo5zjm2n/1/

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<br><p class="p-head">GALLERY</p>
    <hr class="p-div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
        <a href="#"><div class="col-md-3 padding-gallery">
            <div class="gallery-bg"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o"></i><br>         <p>Prom</p></div>
        </div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="col-md-3 padding-gallery">
            <div class="gallery-bg"><i class="fa fa-tree" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><p>Great Outdoors</p></div>
        </div></a>
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
        <a href="#"><div class="col-md-3 padding-gallery">
            <div class="gallery-bg"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-     hidden="true"></i><br><p>City Slickers</p></div>
        </div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="col-md-3 padding-gallery">
            <div class="gallery-bg"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true">    </i><br><p class="gallery-text">Besties Shoots</p></div>
        </div></a>
        <div class="col-md-3">

        </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
```

I want the text to be directly centered under the icons while the content is vertically and horizontally centered.

Thanks for the help!

edit: clarity

Answer (score 0):

in my case. I've removed

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

and added

```
text-align: center;
```

to .gallery-bg and removed

```
position:absolute;
```

from .gallery-bg p

It worked in my case.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I also needed the content to be vertically aligned, so that is why I had the display:flex; justify-content:center;.  Is there another way to do this while keeping the vert alignment centered?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><div class="col-md-3 padding-gallery">
                <div class="gallery-bg">
  <div class="icon_container">
  <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-tree"></i>
<p>Great Outdoors</p>
 </div>
   </div>
            </div></a>
```

CSS:

```
.icon_container{ 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```